# Non-square images no longer show thumbnails in Small Icons or Details view in File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, images, icons, windows-10-v1903

In some previous build (earlier builds of 1809 worked) I was able to see thumbnails for JPGs and PNGs at even the smallest icon sizes in File Explorer. Since I updated to the latest 1809, and then subsequently 1903, only perfectly square images show thumbnails. Non-square images now just show a blank white page icon.

Is there any way to fix this?

Test images are 192 x 128px and 128 x 128px. "Large icons" view mode:

[image]

"Details" view mode:

[image]

As you can see, in Details view mode only the square images have thumbnails. This is a massive pain since I often work in Details view but still need to be able to figure out which image is which without having to open or even just click on every one.